# How to flatten Fuzz ( Fuzz ( Fuzz A))) without having andThen in the fuzz test module?

Tags: elm, elm-test

I have "a parent" `A` type which contains "a child" `B` type.

This is a simplified version of the main data structures i have in my app.

`A` and `B` and `A_id`  and `B_id` are all separate elm modules.

If i can make this simplification work, then maybe is easier to solve my actual problem.

Basically my problem is how to create a fuzzer for `A`.

with the condition that both `A_id` and `B_id` .. need to share the same `A_id`.

```
type A
    = A { id : A_id
        , b : B -- A contains B.
        }

type A_id
    = A_id String

type B
    = B { id : B_id } -- B contains B_id

type B_id
    = B_id ( A_id, String ) -- B_id contains A_id. The exact same A_id as its parent A

a_idFuzzer : Fuzzer A_id
a_idFuzzer =
    Fuzz.string
        |> Fuzz.map A_id

aFuzzer : Fuzzer A
aFuzzer =
    a_idFuzzer
        |> Fuzz.map
            (\a_id ->
                bFuzzer a_id
                    |> Fuzz.map
                        (\b ->
                            -- here i just need the b,
                            -- but in reality i need more children
                            -- for assembling the A data structure.
                            -- i need a C and D with a cFuzzer and a dFuzzer...
                            -- and both C and D depend on having the same A_id value.
                            -- like B does.
                            A
                                { id = a_id
                                , b = b
                                }
                        )
            )



-- im passing A_id as an argument since is generated only once on the parent ( A )
-- and is shared with this B child.

bFuzzer : A_id -> Fuzzer B
bFuzzer a_id =
    Fuzz.string
        |> Fuzz.map (\s -> B_id ( a_id, s ))
        |> Fuzz.map (\id -> B { id = id })
```

So how to create this `Fuzzer A`?

For the code above i get the   `Fuzzer (Fuzzer A)` error as opposed to `Fuzzer A`.

[image: elm nested fuzzer error]

In my actual app i get the more complicated error:

`Fuzzer ( Fuzzer ( Fuzzer ( Fuzzer Exchange )))` vs `Fuzzer Exchange`.

I basically need to flatten it with `andThen` - but no such function exists in the fuzz elm test package - for some not so obvious reason.

**What i tried:**

I'm battling this problem for 3 days - somebody in slack suggested that `andthen` was removed on purpose and i'm supposed to use the `custom` fuzzer - i learned deeper how shrinkers work (i didn't knew them before) and how to use `Fuzz.custom` just to test if they are right.

Fuzz.custom needs a generator and a shrinker.

I can build the generator and generate everything i need,  but  i can't build shrinkers - since the B and A and C and D.. so on are all opaque data structures - in their own module - so i need to get all their properties with getters - in order to shrink them.

So for the example above - to shrink `B` i need to extract the `b_id` and run it trough a shrinker.. and then put that back into `B` by creating a new `B` - using the public api for `B`..  and I don't have public getter api for all the properties I keep on `B`, `C` , `D` etc.. and it just seems wrong to do it this way ( to add getters that i don't need in the app - just for testing purposes.. )

All this mess because `andThen` on the fuzz module was removed... but maybe there is a way, maybe they were right - and i'm not seeing the solution.
Link to the fuzzer module: [here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/1.2.2/Fuzz)

So how to build a fuzzer for `A` datatype?

Any ideas how to deal with this **nested fuzzers**? How to flatten them back to one level?

**Or to phrase it differently, How to build fuzzes that depend on each other like above?** (an example i have on my mind would be - like running an http request that depends on another http request completing before it can start - since it needs the data form the previous request .. this model is seen thought functional programming and is usually done with `andThen` or `bind` or stuff.)

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

> I can build the generator and generate everything i need, but i can't build shrinkers

Then don't bother. Pass [`Shrink.noShrink`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/latest/Shrink#noShrink) to [`Fuzz.custom`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/test/latest/Fuzz#custom). The only disadvantage will come when you have a test that fails, and you will be given several large values of type `A` rather than (ideally) one small one.

As you work with your complex type, you'll get a better sense for how to shrink its values that cause test failures into "smaller" values that still cause test failures. For that matter, you'll get better at generating "interesting" values that find test failures.

In the next major release of elm-test (timeline not set), there will considerable improvements to Shrinkers, including better docs, the removal of lazy lists in favor of regular Elm lists, and renaming to "Simplifier".